# javascript Array in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, variables

Got a strange thing going on, really don't have a idea how to solve this one. Neither did I find useful stuff when googleing.

I have a html form that includes this:

```
<label for="gebied">Gebieden</label>
<div class="button button-selected"><input type="checkbox" name="areas" value="nederland" checked="checked" />Nederland</div>
<div class="button button-selected"><input type="checkbox" name="areas" value="europa" checked="checked" />Europa</div>
<div class="button button-selected"><input type="checkbox" name="areas" value="wereld" checked="checked" />De Wereld</div>
```

Then with javascript (jQuery) I check which are checked and which are not:

```
var areas = [];
$('input[name=areas]:checked').each(function(){
areas.push($(this).val());
 });
```

This is called from within `createShortUrl();`, below in the relevant code:

```
$(function() {
    //Handle things when a buttons is clicked
    $("div.button").click(function() {
        //Find the input field for the clicked div
        var input = $(this).find(':input');
        var inputName = $(input).attr('name');
        //Handle checkboxes, which define the gebied
        if ($(input).is(':checkbox')) {
            //Change the classes
            input.prop('checked', !input[0].checked);
            $(this).toggleClass('button-selected');
        }
        //Handle radio
        if ($(input).is(':radio')) {
            $('form').find('input[name=' + inputName + ']').each(function() {
                $(this).parent('div').toggleClass('button-selected');
                $(this).prop('checked', !input[0].checked);
            });
        }
        //Clicking means something chanhes; create a new short url
        createShortUrl();
    });
});
```

The strange thing is that when in Firefox, when I have earlier checked some of them, they stay in the areas array. Even when I uncheck some of them, they stay in the array and vice versa. But when debugging in Safari, it works like a charm!

When I then uncheck every thing, the array is empty. Recheck some, and there in the array.

So, any ideas, what's going on with Firefox? It looks like FF is caching, even after couple of times refreshing, the previous array. Despite my

> var areas = []

in which I hoped to empty it and rebuild it....

It's live at [here](http://topografieindeklas.nl/jouw-boekje), fired after the large button on the bottom is clicked.

Any thoughts are more then welcome!

Comment: First thought, post jsbin or link to something to debug.

Comment: show more code.. what sort of handler is calling this code? Is array reset every time it is called?

Comment: You don't seem to have any code that reacts to changes of the checkboxes and removes elements from the array.

Comment: Did you use a change event to react the changes ? [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kxe4G/).

Comment: I added the link where the script lives, which must make debugging easier. Sorry I didnt do that yesterday guys.

Comment: @DennisHunink That is not very helpful from a debugging perspective. Could you please make jsFiddle demonstration with only the relevant code?

Comment: @Asad Strange thing is, it works in Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wL5B3/ in firefox too. That's why I did put in the link to the actual website, because something else is causing the problem. Dumping every bit of code from the page in Jsfiddle isnt gone help I guess

Comment: @DennisHunink Check my answer, it should work for you...

Comment: There is a problem with the jsFiddle, in your website, the click won't reach the `checkbox` because of your CSS, it is caught by the `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your event handler. The problem is, the way you are modifying the state of the element does not work in Firefox. You should use `attr()` instead of `prop()` to change the `checked` state.

**Working code:** Replaced `.prop()` with `.attr()`.

```
//Handle things when a buttons is clicked
$("div.button").click(function() {
    console.log("Click");

    //Find the input field for the clicked div
    var input = $(this).find(':input');
    var inputName = $(input).attr('name');

    //Handle checkboxes, which define the gebied
    if ($(input).is(':checkbox')) {
        //Change the classes
        console.log("check");
        input.attr('checked', !input[0].checked);
        $(this).toggleClass('button-selected');
    }

    //Handle radio
    if ($(input).is(':radio')) {
        $('form').find('input[name=' + inputName + ']').each(function() {
            $(this).parent('div').toggleClass('button-selected');
            $(this).attr('checked', !input[0].checked);
        });
    }
    //Clicking means something chanhes; create a new short url
    createShortUrl();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciated you took the time to solve it. Never knew that it didn't worked by the way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the *values* (these are strings) of the inputs into a static array. There is no reason for this array to be updated in tandem with the DOM, in Firefox or in any other browser.

If you were to store the DOM elements themselves in the array and retrieve values from those, that would be a different story.